# How to free up port 22 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In Google Compute Engine, I would like to use port 22 for SFTP although I cannot since the VM says that there is sshd running on this port. Is there any way I can change the port sshd uses to a different one so I can free up 22?

I tried to look at: [How to change sshd port on google cloud instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616395/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-google-cloud-instance), but it did not help and the port for sshd was still 22 after I executed:

```
sudo netstat -pna | grep 22
```

The output is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      53151/sshd    

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      53151/sshd
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you tried to follow instructions [1](https://geekflare.com/cloud-vm-security-guide/#1-Changing-SSH-Default-Port) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616485/12428794) and [3](https://geekflare.com/login-google-cloud-vm/) to change SSH port on your VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the SSH port 22 as per below steps:

1. Log on to the server as an root user
2. Open the SSH configuration file sshd_config with the text editor vi: vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
3. Search for the entry Port 22.
4. Replace port 22 with a port between 1024 and 65536.
5. semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp New-SSH-Port
6. semanage port -l | grep ssh

```
ssh_port_t                     tcp      2222, 22
```

7. systemctl restart sshd
8. netstat -pna | grep 2222

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1525/sshd           
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.33:2222        35.235.241.19:63372     ESTABLISHED 1413/sshd: mdmahboo 
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      1525/sshd
```

9. systemctl status sshd

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-02-21 02:46:55 UTC; 46s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 1525 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1525 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Feb 21 02:46:55 cenos-1 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSSH server daemon.
Feb 21 02:46:55 cenos-1 systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Feb 21 02:46:55 cenos-1 sshd[1525]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
Feb 21 02:46:55 cenos-1 sshd[1525]: Server listening on :: port 2222.
Feb 21 02:46:55 cenos-1 systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

10. Add firewall entry for port 2222 in GCP firewall

Now, you will be able to login to the VM using your custom port number after allowing the port as ingress in firewall rule.

Comment: I did what you proposed, the port of sshd_config is set to 90 now. I restarted the system, then I went to Google Compute web and added a new firewall rule which is ingress tcp:90. And then there is a problem. I want to start SSH but when I try 90, I get an error saying that the connection is not possible. I can only do it on port 22, probably thanks to "default-allow-ssh" firewall rule which opens 22. When I start it on 22 and look what is running on port 22, it is again sshd although sshd_config is changed to 90. Is there something I forgot please?

Comment: I tried port 80 as well. I also tried to change Port in ssh_config to 80 and restart so now both configs are set to 80 and there is also a firewall rule allowing port 80. But no success, I cannot connect on port 80 via window "Open in browser window on custom port". I can only open ssh and start console when I use port 22.

Comment: Please use the port between 1024 and 65536

Comment: I used port 2222 and did the same steps. It is still port 22. I wonder if Google reserves 22 on Compute Engine instances for their processes.

Comment: Add the port in SELinux ```semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222```

Comment: I did the whole process again and it still uses 22. I had the same output as you until step number 8. Then step 8 and 9 showed me port 22 instead of 2222. Maybe this is just some problem with my Linux machine specifically. It seems like it should work with the steps you mentioned so I will mark it as the right answer. Thanks a lot for helping and spending your time to solve it. :)